# subtraction problems are never negative c++

Tags: textpad

Subtraction Problems
 - Both operands should be random numbers in the range, 1 to 999, inclusive
 - But the second operand, (the number being subtracted from the top number) should be less than or equal to the first operand
   This ensures that the answers to subtraction problems are never negative
how do we do this? please help?

Comment: What's the `textpad` tag doing here?

Answer (score 0):

I probably should not answer this, as you didn't put any effort into this question, but I'll outline what to do:

1. Declare two `int` variables, `i1` und `i2`.
2. Set `i1` to random between 1 and 999
3. Set `i2` to random between 1 and `i1`

---

This should read in C like

```
int x = rand() % 999 + 1; 
int y = rand() % x + 1;
```

This should ensure both `x` and `y` are random numbers between 1 and 999 and `y` is less or equal than `x`.

Comment: srand(time(NULL));
     int x = rand() % 900 +1;
     int y = rand() % 900 +1;

     for (x; x<=y; x++)
     {
      int t = x;
      cout <<x;
     }

Comment: both should be between 1 to 999

Comment: I can not do this  Set i1 to random between 1 and 999
Set i2 to random between 1 and i1

Comment: int x = rand() % 900 +1;
     int y = rand() % 900 + 1;
    
      if(x>=y)
      {
       cout << "\n    " << x <<"\n  + " << y <<"\n  -----" << endl ;
      }
      else
      {
       cout << "\n    " << y <<"\n  + " << x <<"\n  -----" << endl ;

Comment: You said both numbers should be random between 1 and 999, but the second should be smaller or equal to the first. This is what I'm saying: First operand `i1` is random between 1 and 999, the second is random between 1 and `i1`. I'll put this into the question.

Comment: Also: Don't put code in comments, put code in your question.